# SQLSERVER FullText search troubleshooting

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with nchar(32) column, with FullText search and auto change tracking activated.

Data set:

```
Name, SuperID 
Item1, (LO}(bJ$
Item2, (LO}(bJ$
Item3, (LO}(bJ$
```

I run two queries:

```
select Name, SuperID from Asset A WHERE A.SuperID LIKE
N'%(LO}(bJ$%'
```

and

```
select Name, SuperID from Asset A WHERE (   CONTAINS
(A.SuperID ,N'"(LO}(bJ$"')  )
```

The first one returns **3** rows, and the second returns only **1** row.

Why is it happening? How can I analyse the contents of the Full Text search index? The column values in the first three results are identical. I have tried to update indexes/stats but that doesn't change the outcome.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried removing quotes around the CONTAINS query but I get an error message:

> "Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition

**UPDATE2:**

I should have phrased my question in a different way, I think! Have a look at the SuperID column values for the three rows that I would like to return. I have converted them to VARBINARY to ensure that there is no hidden trailing space trickery going on and they are actually the same:

```
SuperIDasBinary
0x28004C004F007D00280062004A0024002..
0x28004C004F007D00280062004A0024002..
0x28004C004F007D00280062004A0024002..
```

So why does the CONTAINS query above return only one row instead of three?

Comment: So, either none of the values returned by the first statement have `"(LO}(bJ$"`, or all do? In the first statement, you're matching values that contain `(LO}(bJ$`, in the second `"(LO}(bJ$"`. Just want to confirm that the double quotes aren't making a difference.

Comment: @RDFozz, thank you for commenting. I have will update the question in a second to make it clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst trying to re-create the problem with a fresh table in a separate DB, I ended up comparing the Full-Text catalogue settings. In the DB where I saw the erroneous behaviour the **Table Full-Text Pending Changes** value was 21219 (!).

I have then checked the FT log and found that the Asset table hasn't been updated for a long time:

> An internal query to load data for a crawl on database '-' and table
>   'Asset' failed with error code 1205. Check the sql error code for more
>   information about the condition causing this failure. The crawl needs
>   to be restarted after this condition is removed.

and also

> Error: 30059, Severity: 16, State: 1
>   A fatal error occurred during a full-text population and caused the population to be cancelled.
>   Population type is: AUTO; database name is Media (id: 6); catalog name
>   is - (id: 6); table name Asset (id: 1076966963). Fix
>   the errors that are logged in the full-text crawl log. Then, resume
>   the population. The basic Transact-SQL syntax for this is: ALTER
>   FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name RESUME POPULATION."

I had to manually resume the FT updates. After that the search has returned 3 items!